# Ubuntu 20.10, DNS stops working after ip forwarding enabled

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, dns

as I said my DNS stops working after I enabled ip forwarding, my machine is ubuntu server 20.10.
I've tried setting manually a dns like 1.1.1.1 on resolv.conf but after a couple minits it goes back to the one that it already had attached on the localhost, thanks for the help.

Comment: I solved it using this article: https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18 and later, network configurations are managed by [netplan](https://netplan.io/). The file you should be editing is either `01-netcfg.yaml` or `50-cloud-init.yaml`, instead of `/etc/resolv.conf`. This configuration file will look like this:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        ens3:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses:
            - 10.10.10.2/24
          gateway4: 10.10.10.1
          nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```